# waterfall chart in ggplot2 doesnt seem to render right

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to recreate the waterfall chart as shown in 
https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/ggplot2-wires.pdf 
I am reproducing the code from the link

```
    balance <- data.frame(event = c("Starting\nCash", "Sales", "Refunds",
                                "Payouts", "Court\nLosses", "Court\nWins", "Contracts", "End\nCash"),
                      change = c(2000, 3400, -1100, -100, -6600, 3800, 1400, -2800))

    balance$balance <- cumsum(c(0, balance$change[-nrow(balance)]))
    balance$time <- 1:nrow(balance)
balance$flow <- factor(sign(balance$change))

ggplot(balance) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, colour = "white", size = 2) +
  geom_rect(aes(fill= 'red'),xmin = time - 0.45, xmax = time + 0.45, ymin = balance, ymax = balance) 
                  geom_text(aes(x = time, y = pmin(balance, balance + change) - 50, label = dollar(change)),
                                          hjust = 0.5, vjust = 1, size = 3)

  scale_x_continuous( breaks = balance$time, labels = balance$event) +
                  scale_y_continuous("Balance") +
                  scale_fill_manual(values = c("-1" = "red", "1" = "black"))
```

it throws an error :`Error in scale_x_continuous(breaks = balance$time, labels = balance$event) +  : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

THe final output, per the pdf should look like the image below

[image]

Comment: first, your xmin, xmax etc. should be inside aes()

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of little mistakes, like the aesthetics not being inside `aes()` in `geom_rect()`, missing plus signs after `geom_rect()` and `geom_text()`, and the `ymax` being the same as `ymin`.  In addition, you give a fixed `fill` color when it looks like you want to map `fill` to `factor(flow)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ggplot(balance %>% 
           mutate(flow = factor(flow, labels = c("Negative", "Positive")))) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, colour = "white", size = 2) +
    geom_rect(aes(fill= flow, xmin = time - 0.45, xmax = time+0.45, ymin = change, ymax = balance), 
              color = "black") +
geom_text(aes(x = time, y = pmin(balance, balance + change) - 50, label = change),
          hjust = 0.5, vjust = 1, size = 3) +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = balance$time, labels = balance$event) +
scale_y_continuous("Balance") +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("Negative" = "red", "Positive" = "green"))
```

[image]